# compatibility between NAOqi and ROS

Tags: ros, naoqi, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am very new to the topic NAO and ROS. This is for my thesis at university. I wanna develop a few short programs in ROS but I am not sure if it is compatible with NAOqi. So my only question is: Can i install ROS on my NAO without any problems to also use NAOqi? I wanna use ROS because there exist a connection module (iot_bridge) to interact with NAO and a smarthome framework.

thanks for help

Ralf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220996/compatibility-between-naoqi-and-ros/) by [RalfM](https://answers.ros.org/users/25100/ralfm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simplest way is to keep NAOqi on your robot and install ros on your laptop/desktop computer. There is a [ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/nao) to control NAO and it provides everything you would need.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1